# Angular2 CLI Build Prod Error: Calling function 'NoOpAnimationDriver', function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I switched to using @angular 2.4.4 I started getting the error below.  When I revert to @angular 2.2.1.  I can build without any problems.

When using angular 2.4.4 I can still run my program locally using "npm start".

It's only when I try to run the build using "ng build --prod --aot" that I get the error.

As far as I can tell I'm not using "NoOpAnimationDriver" or "BrowserTestingModule" which are both referenced in the error.

I'm hoping someone has seen this error before and might be able to tell me any of the following: 
1. what the error is really saying.
2. why I'm getting an error in functions that I'm not using.
3. how I might be able to fix the error.
4. where I could look for more information on how to understand errors like these.

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'NoOpAnimationDriver', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AnimationDriver.NOOP in c:/Development/SentriKeyApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/animation_driver.d.ts, resolving symbol BrowserTestingModule in c:/Development/SentriKeyApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser.d.ts, resolving symbol BrowserTestingModule in c:/Development/SentriKeyApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser.d.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'c:\Development\SentriKeyApp\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'c:\Development\SentriKeyApp\src\$$_gendir' in 'c:\Development\SentriKeyApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\linker'
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js 71:15-36 87:15-102
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/linker.js
 @ ./~/@angular/core/src/core.js
 @ ./~/@angular/core/index.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Comment: what version of `angular-cli` are you using?

Comment: Right now I'm using 1.0.0-beta.26.  Before that I was using 1.0.0-beta.21

Comment: in the past I have had similar errors when library versions did not match `angular-cli` defaults. Try creating a new project with `ng init` and compare it's `package.json` with your project's.

Answer (score 1):

The following error is an ahead of time compiler error.

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function ‘declarations’, function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function

**Before:**

```
const declarations = () => [
  SomeComponent
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: declarations(),
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

**After:**

```
export function declarations() {
  return [
    SomeComponent
  ];
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: declarations(),
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.let72omre

Using `-prod` with the `ng build` now defaults to using the Ahead of Time compiler. This has been in effect since beta.28. See here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

`ng build --prod` calls `--aot` as well and looks like the issue is connected with it.

Try to run `ng build --prod --aot false` in order to avoid Ahead-of-Time Compilation

Answer (score 0):

see that blog you'll find an answer
[Getting your angular 2 ready for aot](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad#.tf3rfq5in) and [this](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.uyj5nf2l5)